# Headband tot protect the bluetooth headphone

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have bluetooth headphones and sometimes they fall from my ears. I am usually using a single headphone instead of using both of them.

So I need a headband specially made for protecting bluetooth headphones, if possible with a hole for the other ear.